# When the program built with C::B doesn't work

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks

I made a small c++ project and it was fully compiled and built it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run through c::b it was okay

[image: Hello world!]

However, it says next warnings when I run program outside of the c::b.
"programdir/bin/Debug/program.exe"

[image: When I run program outside c::b]

So I got "libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll" from sourceforge, pasted it next to my .exe file,
and I got 0xc000007b error with the error "cannot start the program"

What should I do in this case of problem?

Comment: Best option may be to add `-static` to your build options. I'm not a Code::blocks user, so I don't know where  you have to slip in this option, but google probably knows.

Comment: google didn't give me any answer, that's why I posted on stackoverflow. I just removed C::B, using VS is much better :)

Comment: Possibly, but you will have the exact same problem running the program on a computer that does not have the correct  Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package installed.